# Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$ .For $B'\subset Y$, prove that $f(f^{-1}(B')) \subset B'$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let us start by noticing that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(B') = \{x\in X \mid f(x)\in B'\} \Longrightarrow f(f^{-1}(B')) = \{f(x)\in Y \mid (x\in X)\wedge(f(x)\in B')\}
\end{align*}

Then I get stuck. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the question, I assume that $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, and B' is a subset of Y (Please mention the hypothesis in your questions!). Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(B'))$. Then there exists $x \in f^{-1}(B')$ such that $y=f(x)$. But $x \in f^{-1}(B')$ so $f(x) \in B'$ and hence $y=f(x) \in B'$. So $f(f^{-1}(B'))\subseteq B'$.

Comment: Thank you so much. The hypothesis are right.